# Querying a remote POP3 Mail server using BASH

Tags: shell-script, email

I'd like to connect to our mail server via POP3, look for a certain pass phrase in the subject and if found then run a script.

How can I achieve this with BASH other than awkwardly scripting Telnet?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The typical tool to query POP3 servers from the commandline is `fetchmail` which you can instruct to leave the original messages on the mail server (the 'keep' option or `nokeep` to empty the mailbox after downloading the messages)  and then `procmail` is the typical mail filter, which can be used to trigger your script.

A sample `.fetchmailrc` would be someting like:

```
poll pop.example.com with proto pop3:
        user "username.on.example" there has password "S3cr3t"
        is herman here and wants ssl nokeep 
        mda "/usr/bin/procmail -t /home/herman/.procmailrc.pop.example.com"
```

And the .procmailrc.pop.example.com file contains a matching rule on a specific Subject: line to trigger your script. The complete message will be passed as STDIN to the script as normally scripts would actually do something with an email message.

```
:0
^Subject: passphrase
| /home/herman/bin/script
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `fetchmail`and `procmail` programs.

`fetchmail` can
* download new POP3 messages with or without deleting them at POP3 server
* pass downloaded messages to another program (procmail) standard input (see `--mda` option)

`procmail` can
* execute custom program/script for messages matching specific critera
 e.g. Subject: matching regular expression